# Remove starting substring http from strings using AWK?

Tags: bash, awk

I'm wondering Is there a better and cleaner way to remove strings at beginning and last of each line in a file using AWK only?

Here's what I got so far

```
cat results.txt | awk '{gsub("https://", "") ;print}' | tr -d ":443"

File: results.txt

https://www.google.com:443
https://www.tiktok.com:443
https://www.instagram.com:443


To get the result

www.google.com
www.tiktok.com
www.instagram.com
```

Comment: if it's always https:// and :443 `awk '{print substr($1,9,length($1)-12)}'`

Comment: Does it have to only be Awk? There are many many tools that can help you out here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With GNU awk.

Use `/` and `:` as field separators and print fourth column:

```
awk -F '[/:]' '{print $4}' results.txt
```

Or use `https://` and `:` as field separators and print second column:

```
awk -F 'https://|:' '{print $2}' results.txt
```

Output:

```
www.google.com
www.tiktok.com
www.instagram.com
```

Comment: Just to add to that solution :

to maximize portability, make them into " [ \ \ / ] " (no spaces in between - it's just all mangled) - nawk whines about the single forward slash, which gawk mawk-1 and mawk-2 all are fine with it. if you're not using quoted strings for regex, then make it one backslash like [ \ / ]

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto: Thanks for the hint. I have added *GNU awk* in my answer to clarify this.

Comment: your solution works just as well with mawk-1 and mawk-2 as well. it's only slightly incompatible with nawk, but i also hardly recommend that junk to anyone.

Answer (score 5):

If it's a list of URLs like that, you could take advantage of the fact that the field separator in `awk` can be a regular expression:

```
awk -F':(//)?' '{print $2}'
```

This says that your field seperator is "`:` optionally followed by `//`", which would split each line into:

```
[$1] http
[$2] www.google.com
[$3] 443
```

And then we print out only field `$2`.

Comment: What are purpose of using ? at the end and (  )  in -F ':(//)?'

Comment: The `?` means "the previous expression, zero or 1 times". In this case, the previous expression is `(//)`, so that's `:` optionally followed by `//`.

Answer (score 1):

```
cat results.txt | awk '{gsub("https://", "") ;print}' | tr -d ":443"
```

I think you are misunderstading what `tr -d` does, it is used to delete enumerated characters (not substring), it does *seems* to do what you want because your test input

```
https://www.google.com:443
https://www.tiktok.com:443
https://www.instagram.com:443
```

do not contain `:` or `4` or `3` which should be kept, if you need test case which will shown malfunction try

```
https://www.normandy1944.info:443
```

Also code as above feature anti-pattern known as *useless use of cat* as GNU `AWK` can deal with file on its' own that is

```
cat results.txt | awk '{gsub("https://", "") ;print}'
```

can be written more succintly as

```
awk '{gsub("https://", "") ;print}' results.txt
```

I would rewrite whole your code (`cat`,`awk`,`tr`) to single `awk` as follows

```
awk '{gsub("^https://|:443$","");print}' results.txt
```

Explanation: replace `https://` following start of line (`^`) or (`|`) `:443` before end of line (`$`) using empty string (i.e. delete these parts) then `print`. Note that `^` and `$` will prevent deleting `https://` and `:443` in middle of strings, though feel free to remove `^` and `$` if you find these to be unlikely.